# How to Restrict Text for Button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am using UIButton i am assigning some text to back button the text is dynamic and i may get bigger length How i can restrict text assigned to the Button some thing like 5 characters?

I am using below @"Some Text" is dynamic.

```
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];

    backButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    [backButton setTitle:**@"some text"** forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBarButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Validate the text before setting it, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes abizem is right and second thing you can set width of this button.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the string to 5 characters, use `substringWithRange`:

```
NSString *newTitle = [origTitle substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, min(5, origTitle.length))];
```

The call `min(5, origTitle.length)` picks the smaller of `5` and the length of the title that you want to set. You need to include `<math.h>` to use `min` function.

Answer (score 0):

check length of your **@"Some text"**  if desired condition true then set on your button